# Frequency of Sound Waves

Tags: waves, acoustics

Is the frequency of the echo (resulted from the reflected sound wave) equal to the frequency of the original sound wave?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the frequency is normally the same.

If the sound is reflected from a moving object then the frequency will be shifted higher or lower depending if the object is moving towards or away from the observer. This is the [Doppler Effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppler_effect).

I have assumed that the observer emits the sound and is not moving. If the observer is moving towards the reflector or away the frequency will also be shifted higher or lower.

If for the example the observer is emitting sound and  moving away from the reflector then the frequency of the sound reflected back will be lower. To calculate this there are two steps. First, the frequency, $f$ received by the stationary reflector needs to be calculated with the doppler formula

$$f={c \over c+ v_s} f_0$$

where $f_0$ is the original frequency, $c$ is the speed of sound in air and $v_s$ is the speed of the source moving away from the reflector.

Now the frequency, $f'$, observed by the moving observer is given by

$$f'={c - v_o\over c } f$$

where $v_o$ is the speed the observer is moving away from the reflector.

Now putting the two equations together and remembering that the observer is the source of the sound (so that $v_s=v_o$) we get

$$f'={c - v_s\over c } f = {c \over c+ v_s} f_0$$

$$f'={c - v_s \over c+ v_s} f_0$$

Comment: If we assume that the observer emits the sound wave and is actually moving away, the apparent frequency would then decrease. How can we calculate the apparent frequency in this case?

Comment: @Lilly reply is edited in to answer

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether the sound wave is being reflected off a stationary or moving object, in which case there would be a doppler shift, otherwise the frequency stays more or less the same.

Comment: If we assume that the observer emits the sound wave and is actually moving away, the apparent frequency would then decrease. How can we calculate the apparent frequency in this case?

Comment: If the reflecting surface is moving, it acts first as a moving observer and then as a moving source.  There will be a double doppler shift upon reflection.  If the source of the sound is moving, that introduces a doppler shift.  If the final observer is also moving, that causes another shift.

Answer (score 0):

You guys are confused between the pitch and frequency.. Wave will loose its upper harmonics with every reflection and if that was a moving surface than our perception will be a lower pith also.

Comment: Can you describe the process by which the wave "loses its upper harmonics?" Can you explain why we would perceive a lower pitch for a reflected sound wave on a moving surface? And who are "you guys?"

Answer (score 0):

Low-frequencies sound waves travel further than high-frequency sound waves so assuming that the original sound is not a pure sine wave but is a mix of frequencies (or is a fundamental frequency with higher-frequency overtones), the echo will have fewer of those high-frequency components because it has traveled further (the pre-echo sound has not traveled at all).

Answer (score -4):

no because wave loose its energy during the propogation. so if energy is lost so its frequency will be decrease.

Comment: The intensity goes down, but this does not change the frequency.